# Is setInterval() method efficient with long timeouts?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sql-insert, scheduling

I am writing an API server with Nodejs and I have a task consisting of multiple (about 3) inserts into a `postgres` database (the task is not heavy) which needs to be run **every week**, is using `setInterval()` method efficient for doing so or other methods such as using crontab are preferable?

Comment: Definitely prefer cron jobs for such long tasks

Comment: Thanks @CertainPerformance. Thought so, was just wondering if there's a more straight forward way to bundle such a function into the server code.